# Do repeated calls to AddHttpClient overwrite each other?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have one NuGet package that has code like this in it:

```
services.AddHttpClient("CompanyStandardClient").AddCompanyAuthenticationHeaders();
```

And another Nuget project with code like this in it:

```
services.AddHttpClient("CompanyStandardClient").AddCompanyHeaderPropagation();
```

Basically, one NuGet sets up my company's authentication, and another sets up the company's header propagation.

I usually would do this code like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient("CompanyStandardClient").AddCompanyAuthenticationHeaders().AddCompanyHeaderPropagation()
```

I am worried that if I do them separate, only one will be in effect.  I looked at the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/7c4f9479b4753a37c8b0669a883002e5e448cc94/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L70) and it returns a `new`ed DefaultHttpClientBuilder for each call.

```
return new DefaultHttpClientBuilder(services, name);
```

But I am not sure if this means that the previous entry was overwritten.

**Can the same named client be "added" separately?  Or will it overwrite?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be done for the same named client based on the internal comments here.

```
    // See comments on HttpClientMappingRegistry.
    private static void ReserveClient(IHttpClientBuilder builder, Type type, string name, bool validateSingleType)
    {
        var registry = (HttpClientMappingRegistry)builder.Services.Single(sd => sd.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClientMappingRegistry)).ImplementationInstance;
        Debug.Assert(registry != null);

        // Check for same name registered to two types. This won't work because we rely on named options for the configuration.
        if (registry.NamedClientRegistrations.TryGetValue(name, out Type otherType) &&

            // Allow using the same name with multiple types in some cases (see callers).
            validateSingleType &&

            // Allow registering the same name twice to the same type.
            type != otherType)
        {
            string message =
                $"The HttpClient factory already has a registered client with the name '{name}', bound to the type '{otherType.FullName}'. " +
                $"Client names are computed based on the type name without considering the namespace ('{otherType.Name}'). " +
                $"Use an overload of AddHttpClient that accepts a string and provide a unique name to resolve the conflict.";
            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }

        if (validateSingleType)
        {
            registry.NamedClientRegistrations[name] = type;
        }
    }
```

[Source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs,634)

The client options configurations will aggregate to a single option.